# Obtain data from SQL and loop in different order

Tags: c#, sql-server

in my application I need to operate with data obtained from SQL SERVER. At first, I grab 5 elements from `table1`:

```
example 1
example 2
example 3
example 4
example 5
```

And now, for **each element in** `array1` I grab 3 elements from `table2`

```
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 4
foo 5
foo 6
foo 7
foo 8
foo 9
foo 10
foo 11
foo 12
foo 13
foo 14
foo 15
```

Allright. What I would like to do now is to loop them in that order:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

(I cant post third image because Im new member, but you know the idea.)

To do this I adeed data to arrays:

```
arrayExample[5]
+----------+
| example0 |
+----------+
| example1 |
+----------+
| example2 |
+----------+
| example3 |
+----------+
| example4 |
+----------+

arrayFoo[5,3]
+--------+--------+--------+
| foo 0  | foo 1  | foo 2  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| foo 3  | foo 4  | foo 5  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| foo 6  | foo 7  | foo 8  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| foo 9  | foo 10 | foo 11 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| foo 12 | foo 13 | foo 14 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

And I loop them with:

```
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            DoActions(arrayExample[j], arrayFoo[i,j]);
        }
    }
```

And It works. But now I would like to get more data from SQL server. I would need to create more and more dimensions of my arrays. I think its too complicated. There must be a better solution to do this.

tl;dr

I want to grab 5 elements `EXAMPLE` and each of wchich should have assigned 3 `FOO` elements.

Now loop every elements with first `FOO` asigned, then second and then third.

DO you have any better idea than mine?

Comment: This sounds just like the thing classes and lists/hashsets/dictionaries were made for. How about a Dictionary<string,HashSet<Foo>>() where example is the string key (assuming all examples are unique?

Comment: I do not really get what you want... Are you searching for a way to get combined data from SQL Server (read about `CROSS JOIN`) or do you need advise, how one could store / model this in C#? Or do you need advise how one could query this? What is your goal?

Comment: If you'd care to tell me what types are example and foo, I can provide an example -- or really ALL the types you want to add.

Comment: Lets say you have a table with Friends and second table with Food. Every friend have to eat 3 food. But in that order: Friend1 eats his first food, Friend2 eats his first food, Friend3 eats his first food etc..

Comment: @HamBurg, a simple SQL query would do this for you, a complex m:n related object model would do this for you... I have still no idea what you really need...